# Windows cmd: Piping dir output into start

Tags: command-line, windows-10, piping

So suppose I know there's some file(s) (all with the same extension) in my directory which I want to run only I don't know their name.

I could execute the following to get all the relevant file names (.ext is just an arbitrary extension here)

```
dir /b /a-d *.ext
```

And then I could call

```
start
```

on all those files.

But I'd like to skip a step and simply pipe the output from dir into start.

I've tried

```
dir /b /a-d *.ext | start
```

but all that does is open an empty shell. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's no need for a pipe. Use `for %%a in (*.ext) do start "" "%%a"`. By default `for` loops over a wildcard set and ignores directories.

Comment: Avoid using `for /f` to pipe the output of `dir` from a sub-shell. The filenames will be encoded using the console codepage (OEM default), piped, and then decoded using the console codepage. Unless you use chcp.com to temporarily set the console to UTF-8 (65001), then you're asking for problems since filenames are the full range of Unicode.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks a lot @eryksun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem *.exe | ForEach-Object { Start-Process $_ }
```

shorter (with aliases):

```
gci *.exe | % { start $_ }
```

Comment: Note that this PowerShell pipe is a very different beast from a pipe in CMD. PowerShell uses an object pipeline, which is not, and usually does not involve, an OS-level pipe (i.e. a file opened on \Device\NamedPipe).

Comment: Sure; never claimed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
 dir /b /a-d *.ext > start.bat
```

This will generate a  start.bat file. Then:

```
call start.bat
```

By running the file you will run all apps.

Comment: For the sake of laziness, I was hoping to find a 1-line solution. But this is a solid enough solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can do in one line using PowerShell (see my answer).